# How can I get data from a website to ios app

Tags: ios, web, request

I want to create an iOS app that can show the bike stations and their availability(how many bikes are available in each station) from a website and I want to know how can I do it (which request?...)

Comment: Use an API that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways you can do that.

First you should investigate if the BIKE Data Website offers a Web Service that you can utilize ? I suspect not. Then you create your Own Web service (I think it will be ideal to create REST - http/JSON) type service since that is lighter in comparison to the SOAP.

In your Service You will need to do a HTTP Request on the URL where the data is, html will be returned from the page, then look through the html and parse and get the data you need and return values to your app.

I hope this provides a pointer.

Thanks

Comment: can you give me an example to a HTTP Request that returns HTML
Thank you